# Meteor unique document field?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Im trying to build a learning app where at the moment it needs to get the first 7 posts from a subreddit and then if that is not already in the database add it to the database. However it runs both the if and else 7 times each for some reason and I cannot figure out why. Here is the helper method:

```
Template.posts.helpers({
  posts : function () {
    Meteor.call('getPosts', "tifu", function(e, results){
      var result = JSON.parse(results.content).data.children;
      Session.set('postsResults', result);
    });
    for(var i=0; i<7; i++){
      var result = Session.get('postsResults')[i].data;
      if(Posts.find({r_id: result.id}).count() == 0){
        console.log("if");
      } else {          
        console.log("else");
      };
    };
    return Posts.find();
  }
});
```

and the html side:

```
<template name="posts">
    <div class="col-md-12 posts-div">
      {{#each posts }}
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">{{ title }}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">{{{ body }}}</div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
              <div class="col-md-2">{{ score }}</div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">{{ subreddit }}</div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">{{ createdBy }}</div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
          </div>
        </div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
    <hr>
</template>
```

I have replaced the insert code with simple console logs and these are the results I get:

```
if
if
if
if
if
if
if
else
else
else
else
else
else
else
```

When I run the `Posts.find({r_id: result.id}).count() == 0` in the console I get false same with `Posts.findOne({r_id: result.id}) == null` but for some reason in javascript file it still runs the true portion and I then end up with like 50 copies of the same post which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Well thats because helpers runs async, so first the == 0 its true and then the other statement its true thats what you get the other consoles for example pine `console.log(Posts.find({r_id: result.id}).count())` inside the if statement and you will get `0` and lester in 1 sec you will get another number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not optimal to use `Meteor.call` in a helper. The helper's `function` will re-run every time there is a reactive change. This is why it runs so many times.

Use the `Template.onCreated` callback instead:

```
Template.posts.onCreated(function() {
    Meteor.call('getPosts', "tifu", function(e, results){
        var result = JSON.parse(results.content).data.children;
        Session.set('postsResults', result);
    });
});
```

And your helper:

```
Template.posts.helpers({
  posts : function () {
    var r = Session.get('postsResults')

    for(var i=0; i<7; i++){
        if(!r) continue;
        var result = r[i].data;
        if(Posts.find({r_id: result.id}).count() == 0){
          console.log("if");
        } else {          
          console.log("else");
        };
      };
    return Posts.find();
  }
});
```

Second thing to keep in mind is `Session.get('postsResults')` *will* be `null` while the result of `Meteor.call` is returned, for a few hundred milliseconds. If you do `Session.get('postsResults')[i].data` you will get an exception.

This is why i added a conditional check to continue the loop if `r` is null. This way you wait for the result and the `posts` `function` will re-run and recalculate the results with the new data.